# Boost converter depending on load

Tags: transistors, boost, duty-cycle, step-up

**TL;DR:** Output voltage of boost converter depends on load. I assume because the load is altering the voltage between the base of the boost transistor and ground, thus altering the duty cycle. No idea how to solve that.

Context: I am trying to charge a Lithium battery using a 2V solarcell. I burnt the original converter, so I wanted to build one by myself for the fun of it. As I am a mechanical engineer, I don't have that much knowledge about electronics.

In the design of the boost converter there is not much to vary. The switching signal is created by the Meissner circuit, which is powered by the battery (or the solar cell, I am not that fixed on it yet). I simulated the circuit using LTspice (nice tool, btw).

Anyway, I observed that the output voltage is dependent on the load (resistance).

I assume this is because the voltage between the base of Q1 and ground depends on the resistance, thus altering the dutycycle.
[image: See the differing output voltage]

Sadly, I have no idea how to overcome this problem.
Any suggestions? A simulation and sketch of the circuit can be seen in the picture below. If necessary/desired I will supply/upload said LTspice sketch.

[image: Circuit Layout]

Comment: *Any suggestions?* - do some research and read about boost converters is my advice. Your circuit will not work to control output voltage without extensive redesign. [Maybe this might help in some way](http://www.stades.co.uk/Boost%20converter/Boost%20calculator.html) (maybe eventually, if you stick at it). It's called an Armstrong oscillator BTW and will be the wrong approach unfortunately.

Comment: @Andyaka  it would be fine for me to have fixed input output ratio, no need for regulation. I did some research about boost converters and the ratio of input and output should only depend on the duty cycle.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy it is oscillating just fine. Do you mean settling times/charging times by “transient”?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I added pictures of where you can see the load dependence. The Current in L3 for the left (R=10) variies between 0.94 to 1.10 A and for the right (R=0.01) between 1.39 A to 1.43 A

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119295/discussion-between-math-keeps-me-busy-and-94bb494nd41f).

Comment: If the voltage is changing with the load that is an indication that you are overloading it. If this is true it will eventually get hot and become smoke.

Comment: I don't know about that thurr oscillator, I prefer to build a voltage controllable 0-100% pwm generator out of 555 timers and then you can build different control/feedback circuits to vary the duty cycle.  Fun thing is once you build it you can drive buck or boost or cuk or other topology with it by changing the control circuit.  You have no feedback and no reference voltage, so you can't expect load regulation.